# How do I log out from Stack overflow when on windows 10 using Chrome

Tags: discussion, logout

I have clicked all the menu options, as well as clicked around in the user and profile sections, but I will can't find an option to logout. The attacked screenshot is marking with red crosses where I have unsuccessfully tried to find a way of logging out.
[image: Screenshot of the Stack Overflow interface in Chrome desktop browser.]

Answer (score 4):

Click on the right most icon, logout option is right next to the current community
[image: sample screenshot]